# /lib/libmatrix.a: file not recognized: File format not recognized collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile a makefile which includes the following line:

```
gcc -I. -I/home/usr/Documents/MTV/include -ggdb3 -Wall -O2 -o ascii2bin.c \
    -L. -L../lib -lmatrix -lseq_io -lpic -lm
```

And this is what I get:

```
../lib/libmatrix.a: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any idea on what might happen to libmatrix.a? How can I read what's inside libmatrix.a? I tried using the 'ar -t' command, but it also says file format not recognized.

The project was compiled on Cygwin before by others, and now I'm using ubuntu gcc to try to redo it, could this be the problem?

Comment: How are you trying to "compile a Makefile"?

Comment: @H2CO3 `make` is a compiler.

Comment: well, i meant using the command 'make'.

Comment: @Casey euh, no, it's a build automation tool. Not even remotely a compiler.

Comment: Where did the .a file come from?  Perhaps it is not intended for this system.

Comment: Does `file ../lib/libmatrix.a` tell you anything useful?

Comment: @ChrisStratton: '-lmatrix' refers to the libmatrix.a that i was talking about.

Comment: @twalberg: I'm not sure what you meant, but that's just the path to the library. I think there's some problem with the library itself.

Comment: @htann1900 I mean, what does running the command `file ../lib/libmatrix.a` return? Perhaps you aren't familiar with the `file` command that attempts to identify the type of a particular file by checking for headers and other identifying structure?

Comment: Let me ask that again - where did you get this .a file that you are referencing with the -l, and what makes you think it is appropriate for your system?

Comment: If `../lib` is part of the same source tree, try cleaning it out and remaking it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: The library was made before by others. I am just trying to recompile the program. It compiled fine on Cygwin. There are probably some little things that i need to change to make it work on ubuntu

Comment: If that .a library file worked on cygwin, it **will not** work on linux.  You will need to recompile it from source into a library suited for linux, matching the ABI and even versions of other libraries on which it might depend, of your system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A library file built for cygwin will not work on linux.

The library itself must be recompiled from source to match the details (ABI, dynamic system library dependencies, etc) of the system on which it is intended to be used.

Cygwin tries to be *source compatible* with Linux, so if you have the source rebuilding may be straightforward.   But it is not binary-compatible, and libraries are basically binary building blocks with metadata to permit linking them together.